# UITextView is clipped after applying a transform and setting new typing attributes

Tags: ios, uitextview, clip

I have a `UITextView` that can be scaled and rotated. Its text is edited by the user. Text attributes can be changed too e.g. text and background color, font, etc.

Now the funny thing, if I apply a scale transform which *shrinks* the view (e.g. 0.5), then its text is clipped. Behaviour is the same if I set `view.transform` or `view.layer.transform`. It is caused by the internal `UITextContainerView` which looks like it is scaled twice e.g. if the text view is scaled 0.5x then the `UITextContainerView` has half size of the shrunken text view. The `frame` and `bounds` of the `UITextContainerView` have the same value and it is the size of the shrunk text view, which looks like it is correct. `UITextContainerView` transform and its layer's transform are identity.

[image]

Manually changing the `frame` and `bounds` of the `UITextContainerView` is automatically reset thus does not work. Also `clipsToBounds` and `masksToBounds` do not fix the clipping.

This is happening on iOS 11.4 in simulator and in real devices. If I remove just the setting of new typing attributes, then the `UITextContainerView` behaves correctly and the text is not clipped.

This is casing issues, if I remove it then the text is not clipped anymore:

```
textView.typingAttributes = updatedTypingAttributes
```

Anyone hit this bug? How can I solve this?

Comment: I am having this exact issue. We allow the user to enter text and they can pinch to scale the textview, but after a while, the UITextContainerView's bounds becomes smaller than the UITextView. How did you fix this?

Comment: @ahoang see the accepted answer please. tl;dr; wrap the text view in another view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed this OS bug with wrapping the text view in another `UIView` and apply the transform to the `UIView` instead of the textview inside.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by overriding `transform` on my `UITextView` subclass. No need for a parent `UIView`.

```swift
override var transform: CGAffineTransform {
    didSet {
        guard transform != oldValue else { return }

        // alternatively, if transform == .identity
        if transform.a == 1 {
            setNeedsLayout()
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution if you can use a subclass.